# TSL/SSL handskahe failing on IIS hosted APP

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, tls1.2

I know this is a topic asked many times, yet none of the already provided answers helped me.

I have an Asp.NET Web APi on NetFramework 4.7.2
From one of the controllers an http request is made that fails every time when hosted on IIS but not on debug.

On the windows server 2008 where IIS is hosted:

- TLS 1.2 is turned on in the registry
- Strong Encryption is turned on in the registry
- Certificate of target url is in a trusted store

This is how clien is created:

```
        _clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip };
        _clientHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; 
        _clientHandler.Proxy = null;
        _clientHandler.UseProxy = false;

        _client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler);
```

This is request message:

```
        using (var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
            {
                message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                using (var content = CreateUrlContent(request))
                {
                    message.Content = content;

                    using (var response = await _client .SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                    {
                        return await Deserialize<Models.Token.AccessTokenResponse>(response);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now exception returned is:

```
    {
        "Type": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
        "Message": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
        "Data": {},
        "InnerException": {
            "Type": "System.Net.WebException",
            "Status": "SecureChannelFailure",
            "Message": "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL\/TLS secure channel.",
            "Data": {},
            "TargetSite": "System.IO.Stream EndGetRequestStream(System.IAsyncResult, System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)",
            "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)",
            "Source": "System",
            "HResult": -2146233079
    },
```

Now here is trace for the fail (i have renamed the real URL/IP and removed secret key):

```
        System.Net Information: 0 : [7608] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5424] Entering HttpWebRequest#45858001::HttpWebRequest(https://secret.Url.To.Hide.Com/token#1252827567)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [5424] RAS supported: True
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5424] Exiting HttpWebRequest#45858001::HttpWebRequest() 
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5424] Entering HttpWebRequest#45858001::HttpWebRequest(uri: 'https://secret.Url.To.Hide.Com/token', connectionGroupName: '42319532')
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5424] Exiting HttpWebRequest#45858001::HttpWebRequest() 
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5424] Entering ServicePoint#54863560::ServicePoint(secret.Url.To.Hide.Com:443)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [5424] Associating HttpWebRequest#45858001 with ServicePoint#54863560
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6548] Entering HttpWebRequest#45858001::BeginGetRequestStream()
    System.Net Information: 0 : [6548] Associating Connection#7412602 with HttpWebRequest#45858001
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Entering Socket#63549928::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Exiting Socket#63549928::Socket() 
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Entering Socket#47270543::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Exiting Socket#47270543::Socket() 
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Entering DNS::TryInternalResolve(secret.Url.To.Hide.Com)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Entering Socket#63549928::BeginConnectEx()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Entering Socket#63549928::InternalBind(0.0.0.0:0#0)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Exiting Socket#63549928::InternalBind() 
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6548] Exiting Socket#63549928::BeginConnectEx()    -> ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#3708755
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [6548] Exiting HttpWebRequest#45858001::BeginGetRequestStream()     -> ContextAwareResult#31973720
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Entering Socket#63549928::EndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#3708755)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Entering Socket#63549928::InternalEndConnect(ConnectOverlappedAsyncResult#3708755)
    System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [3268] Socket#63549928 - Created connection from 10.3.18.21:49787 to 193.86.xx.xxx:443.
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Exiting Socket#63549928::InternalEndConnect() 
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Exiting Socket#63549928::EndConnect() 
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Entering Socket#47270543::Close()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Entering Socket#47270543::Dispose()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Exiting Socket#47270543::Close() 
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] Connection#7412602 - Created connection from 10.3.18.21:49787 to 193.86.xx.xxx:443.
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] TlsStream#19483210::.ctor(host=secret.Url.To.Hide.Com, #certs=0, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=None)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] Associating HttpWebRequest#45858001 with ConnectStream#23811154
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] HttpWebRequest#45858001 - Request: POST /token HTTP/1.1
    
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] ConnectStream#23811154 - Sending headers
    {
    Authorization: Basic YOU DO NOT NEED TO SEE SECRET KEY HERE
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Host: secret.Url.To.Hide.Com
    Content-Length: 289
    Expect: 100-continue
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    }.
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] SecureChannel#21312719::.ctor(hostname=secret.Url.To.Hide.Com, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] Enumerating security packages:
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     Negotiate
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     NegoExtender
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     Kerberos
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     NTLM
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     Schannel
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     WDigest
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     TSSSP
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     pku2u
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268]     CREDSSP
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] SecureChannel#21312719 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] SecureChannel#21312719::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord, UseStrongCrypto), m_ProtocolFlags=(Zero), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = secret.Url.To.Hide.Com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [3268] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=164, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Entering Socket#63549928::BeginSend()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3268] Exiting Socket#63549928::BeginSend()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#55998275
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Data from Socket#63549928::PostCompletion
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000000 : 16 03 03 00 9F 01 00 00-9B 03 03 62 3C 1A 7E 16 : ...........b<.~.
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000010 : E3 DC 6F 9F 75 12 6F E1-2B 57 9E CB 88 6E 45 62 : ..o.u.o.+W...nEb
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000020 : C8 2B F2 7A 1A 9C 7D 72-F1 CA 22 00 00 20 C0 28 : .+.z..}r..".. .(
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000030 : C0 27 C0 14 C0 13 C0 2C-C0 2B C0 24 C0 23 C0 0A : .'.....,.+.$.#..
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000040 : C0 09 00 9D 00 9C 00 3D-00 3C 00 35 00 2F 01 00 : .......=.<.5./..
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000050 : 00 52 00 00 00 1B 00 19-00 00 16 6F 69 64 63 2E : .R.........oidc.
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000060 : 73 61 6E 64 62 6F 78 2E-62 61 6E 6B 69 64 2E 63 : sandbox.bankid.c
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000070 : 7A 00 0A 00 08 00 06 00-19 00 18 00 17 00 0B 00 : z...............
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000080 : 02 01 00 00 0D 00 14 00-12 06 01 06 03 04 01 05 : ................
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000090 : 01 02 01 04 03 05 03 02-03 02 02 00 17 00 00 FF : ................
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 000000A0 : 01 00 01 00                                     : ....
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Entering Socket#63549928::EndSend(OverlappedAsyncResult#55998275)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Exiting Socket#63549928::EndSend()   -> Int32#164
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Entering Socket#63549928::BeginReceive()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Exiting Socket#63549928::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#29428925
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Data from Socket#63549928::PostCompletion
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] 00000000 : 15 03 03 00 02                                  : .....
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Entering Socket#63549928::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#29428925)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Exiting Socket#63549928::EndReceive()    -> Int32#5
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Entering Socket#63549928::BeginReceive()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [9712] Exiting Socket#63549928::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#23934571
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8176] Data from Socket#63549928::PostCompletion
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8176] 00000000 : 02 28                                           : .(
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8176] Entering Socket#63549928::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#23934571)
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8176] Exiting Socket#63549928::EndReceive()    -> Int32#2
    System.Net Information: 0 : [8176] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = bc0e160:3343330, targetName = secret.Url.To.Hide.Com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [8176] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8176] Entering Socket#63549928::Dispose()
    System.Net Error: 0 : [8176] Exception in HttpWebRequest#45858001:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [8176] Entering HttpWebRequest#45858001::EndGetRequestStream()
    System.Net Error: 0 : [8176] Exception in HttpWebRequest#45858001::EndGetRequestStream - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7504] ServicePoint#54863560::CloseConnectionGroupInternal(42319532)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7504] ServicePoint#54863560::CloseConnectionGroupHelper(connectionGroupName=42319532, closeInternal=True)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7504] ServicePoint#54863560::ReleaseConnectionGroup(42319532S>I>&<>c#55601314::<.ctor>b__19_0)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7504] ServicePoint#54863560::ReleaseConnectionGroup, returning(true)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7504] ServicePoint#54863560::CloseConnectionGroupHelper, returning(True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that TLS 1.2 has turned on the server, even you set it in registry.

This [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-) shows that Windows Server 2008 doesn't support TLS1.2.
[image]

When the server doesn't support the TLS version which client need, this message will also be reported. So you need to update server to 2012 or 2016. Server 2019 and 2022 are better. Then check if the TLS connection can be created.

Comment: Support to windows server 2008 was later added by Microsoft in a update. Server is fully updated.

Comment: Can you share the link or any release note of that update? I need to confirm it.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2017/07/20/tls-1-2-support-added-to-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Thank you for sharing. If you access the API url in browser, can browser create the connection and show the TLS version? Or you can this tool check if the server enable TLS1.2.   https://geekflare.com/tools/tls-test

Comment: If I connect in a browser on the server everything is ok.

Comment: Does the client machine support TLS1.2? Did you try to use other client machine to send TLS1.2 request?

Comment: Hello, sorry for long pause. In the end we tried almost everything. It just seems that even tho Microsoft says that TLS was in the service pack, it wasnt. So we decided to scrap the server and made and update to a new OS.